# PayPal Money Request automation in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

I have a button on my page (ASP.NET MVC 3) redirecting to the PayPal service.

I want to automate some process in my system, and I want to allow users to send the Money Request using PayPal.

But, is it possible to pass to the PayPal service (via URL ?) the Recipient's email address, amount and Request payment type (Goods/Services) ?

After the user is logged in, all that fields will be filled in. I'm totally new with that scenario, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a checkout form in your site and use paypal IPN.

When you create the check out form, you need to store in your database all the values the user gives you. Then send paypal the information you want using the IPN.

The IPN will come back telling you that the transaction was approved or not.

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67TtKPC-qmE).

Comment: if I'm understanding it correncly, I have to get from each user his data (these which are required) for IPN ? I'm talking about the scenario from the opposite side - I'll generate a PayPal URL containing my email and amount. What will user do is to sign in the PayPal and accept sending the money request. Is that possible ?

Comment: I have not seen links, but you can generate paypal buttons dynamically. YES.